# Dynamically changing a Wordpress menu page with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, dynamic

I am trying to change a page in the Wordpress menu dynamically. That is, I dont want to change the menu itself, but the page that is displayed in the backend. I am using jquery to add a div once a button is clicked. My javascript function looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#show").click(function(){
        $(".some_div").after("<div>I am added</div>").attr('class', 'some_class');      
    });
});
```

The button that is clicked submits a form and looks like this

```
<input type="submit" name="show" id="show" value="Show Me" class="button-primary" />
```

Once the button is clicked, the script works fine by adding the div briefly. The problem is, that the page is reloaded as well and the html code is "reset" so that the added div disappears again. Does anyone know a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#show").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".some_div").after("<div>I am added</div>").attr('class', 'some_class');      
    });
});
```

Comment: Does this prevent the form from beeing submitted? I wld still need to get the form data on click

Comment: You could use this: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started I guess, it gives you HTML forms and AJAX submission

Comment: @Marco K: Yes; to post the form through jQuery then, you can use [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) after appending the `<div>` in your `.click()`'s function.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent the default behavior of the form button by using preventDefault(), would work like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myForm").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".some_div").after("<div>I am added</div>").attr('class', 'some_class');      
    });
});
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/submit/